# Hide div when loading from an iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook

What's wrong with this code of mine? Thanks for any clue.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
   if(window.name != "") {document.getElementById("toggleText").style.display = 'none';}
</script>

 <div id="toggleText"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: accept at least solution, if issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a div that has not been parsed yet. Put the javascript after the HTML code, or make it run on onLoad (or document.ready or such)

Comment: Thanks primavera133. You provided two solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

Place this code `<div id="toggleText"> Hello </div>` above script tag

you are trying to hide the element which is not in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

write your code on ready function, actually you are trying to access an element before its loading in DOM

like that

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 try {
       if(window.name != "") 
       {
         document.getElementById("toggleText").style.display ='none';
       }   
     }  
    catch (e) { alert("Error:  " + e); }
});
```